# WAMP Solid Orange and staying there

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am running windows8.1 and the system locked up. We had to shut the system down.
When it came back up WAMP Icon wouldn't move off orange.

Error found was:
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

So I went into the wamp server (2.5) interface, clicked on Apache, Version and then the version number (as suggested on another post) and that seemed to take care of that error as I haven't seen it since.

But WAMP still orange

I tested port 80 and it says:
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12.

Nothing in the Apache error files that indicates a problem

Nothing in the Mysql log.

I reinstalled both Apache and Mysql services.

Anyone have anything that I can look at that might direct me to the problem?
I desperately do not want to reinstall WAMP as I have a bunch of innodb tables.

Thanks for any lifeline.
Jim

Comment: I was able to get to green by adding the following to the my.ini file:          InnoDB_force_recovery = 2.  Then exported all the InnoDB tables, then trashed them all from the database, then restarted WAMP (Green), Then imported the InnoDB tables back in.  It was a bit of a hail Mary, because there was no indication that there was a corrupt table causing the problem.

Comment: Should just add that between changing the ini, I restarted WAMP with the new change and that allowed be access to the database and the ability to export the InnoDB tables to a folder.

Comment: Right so for others that read this: The first issue was a Corrupt Database due to a system crash. The second issue was that no backups had been taken.